# Execute Command at Start of Chapter

Tags: chapters, automation, lettrine

So i've recently found out about the `lettrine`-package and want to use it in my reports. The basic usage is:

```
\lettrine{E}{in} erstes Beispiel...
```

There can be optional arguments like

```
\lettrine[lines=4]{E}{in} zweites Beispiel...
```

Now i'm wondering if i can automate the process of using that package. I want to enlarge the first letter at the start of each chapter! Is there a way to configure LaTeX so that i can fully omit typing `\lettrine...` and so forth and just start my chapters with `Ein erstes Beispiel` (referring to the previous examples)?

Comment: well it depends a bit how robust you want to be, you need to find the first letter and first word, which is easy if the text starts `Ein erstes` but can be arbitrarily hard if it starts `\'{E}in  erstes` or `\textbf{Foo bar} zzz` or `A cat sat on a mat` or  `\somelocallydefinedmacro` ... or `\section{the next heading}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stupid version that proofs that it is indeed possible, but breaking for any of the cases mentioned by [@DavidCarlisle after "can be arbitrarily hard"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463100/execute-command-at-start-of-chapter/463101#comment1165044_463100). Don't really use this!

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@chapter\firstlettrine{}{}
\apptocmd\@schapter\firstlettrine{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lettrine}

\def\firstlettrine #1#2 
  {%
    \lettrine{#1}{#2}
  }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
This is a first example. \blindduck

\blindduck[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]